# How to apply the Fourier sine transform on this equation?

Tags: fourier-transform, boundary-value-problem

Here's a question of the Laplace equation in a semi-infinite strip with the Dirichlet Data:

$$
U_{xx}+U_{yy}=0,\qquad 0<x<\infty, \ 0<y<b
$$
The boundary conditions are given as
$$
u(0,y)=0,u(x,b)=0, u(x,0) = f(x)
$$

To solve this problem, we use the Fourier sine transformation with respect to x, and here're the equations and boundary conditions after the transformation:

$$
\frac{d^2}{dy^2}U_s-k^2U_s = 0\qquad [1], \\U_s(k,b) = 0, U_s(k,0) = F_s(k)
$$
I'm still confused about how did we obtain the equation [1], and where does $k^2$ come from? Also, how can we find the general solution of the equation [1]? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: The Fourier sine transform is given by $$g_{s}\propto\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \sin(kx) dx$$ up to a scaling, depending on your definition of the Fourier transform. Letting $g=U$, then integration by parts implies $\partial_{x}^{2}U\to -k^{2} U_{s}$ assuming $U$ has enough regularity. Nothing changes in the $y$ coordinate, so that $\partial_{y}^{2}U\to\partial_{y}^{2}U_{s}$. Then you also need to transform your boundary conditions. You now have a second order ODE to solve and so you can guess the solution is of the form $U_{s}(k,y) = A(k)\exp(\lambda y)$ for some $\lambda$ and see what comes out.

Comment: @mattos Thanks so much for the comment! Could you explain a bit more about  the integration by parts here?

Comment: What is there to say? $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} U_{xx} \sin(kx) dx = U_{x} \sin(kx) \bigg\lvert_{\mathbb{R}} - k \int_{\mathbb{R}} U_{x} \cos(kx) dx =0 - k \int_{\mathbb{R}} U_{x}\cos(kx) dx = \dots$$ where the evaluated term vanishes as $U$ is required to be integrable.

Comment: @mattos Thank you!